# org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1] - how to solve?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

**JsonArray Is:**

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "name": abc,
      "start_date": "2017-5-18 0:30:00",
      "end_date": "2017-6-1 0:30:00",
      "start_address": "Gujarat 380060, India",
      "end_address": "Ognaj, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India"
    },
    {
      "name": pqr,
      "start_date": "2017-5-18 0:30:00",
      "end_date": "2017-6-1 0:30:00",
      "start_address": "Gujarat 380060, India",
      "end_address": "Ognaj, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India"
    }
  ]
}
```

java code using springBoot is bellow

> @RequestMapping(value = "/addabc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
>
> @CrossOrigin
>   public Map addabc(@RequestBody String
>   data,             HttpServletRequest request) {
>
> JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(data);
>
> try{
>
> ```
> for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
>   JSONObject jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
>    ......
>    ......
>
> }
> ```
>
> }catch (Exception e) { ...
>   }

**Getting exception is:-**

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433) ~[json-20140107.jar:na]
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:105) ~[json-20140107.jar:na]
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:144) ~[json-20140107.jar:na]
    at com.abc.io.controller.abcController.addabc(abcController.java:214) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(Abstract.......
```

when i convert json array into JSONArray class then getting exception. How can i handle json array to JSONArray.

Comment: The message is pretty clear. The JSON you have is not a JSON array. Arrays start with a `[`. What you have is a JSON object. It has a single attribute, named "list", whose type is a JSON array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the JSON you given is not an array. Only the `"list"` object is an array.

Second, the value of `"name"` should be in `""` (like `"name": "pqr",`) in both object in `"list"`. So provided json is not valid.

For valid json following code is giving you the `JSONObject` from `JSONArray`

```
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(data);

        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) json.get("list");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonobject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            .....
            .....
        }
```

Comment: Can't cast JSonArray to JsonObject

Comment: @SecondView `JSONArray.get(i)` return an `Object`. So no way you can't do that!

Comment: but there is exception i faced when i try your way it say can't cast

Comment: Then create it as a new question!